# android ..return list object from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get Item object from firebase realtime database. Every thing working well but the images list return null.

Comment: I think you have to look closely at your pojo class and json in firebase, probably those items are not parse well

Comment: Don't post a link to an image of code. Instead edit your question to include the [minimum code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it provides information on how to create such an MCVE, why it's useful, and much more).

Comment: iam beginer in stackoverflow

Comment: just add some code here or paste the code link from pastebin.

Comment: you may be beginner in SO but u should have learned how to ask question I guess

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have some class Item with following data members

```
public class Item {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("images")
    @Expose
    private List<String> images;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(List<String> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

}
```

Now you are using this class for firebase mapping and uploading.
Lets upload our Item class members as the key-value pair.

```
mDatabase.push().setValue(getItemReady(), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        if (databaseError == null) {
            makeToast("One entry created successfully");
        } else {
            //data creation failed, handle it here
        }
    }
});

private Item getItemReady() {
    List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();
    images.add("https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWkC2.png");
    Item mItem = new Item();
    mItem.setName("mutee aljabri");
    mItem.setImages(images);
    return mItem;
}
```

The above call will map the POJO to json much like below one on firebase.

```
{
  "name":"mutee aljabri",
  "images" 
    "0":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWkC2.png"
}
```

If this is true then we are doing it right, so now lets parse it back on client side on request.

```
private void getDataFirebase() {
    //get fresh data here
    ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "load items : onDataChanged() " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //here it will parse every Item you have pushed to firebase
                Item item = snapshot.getValue(Item.class);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting data failed, log a message
            Log.d(TAG, "load events : onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    };
    mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
}
```

I hope you did it pretty close to what i am doing.

Comment: its necessary to add annotations in POJO class (Item)

Comment: I wanna to use images in FireBaseRecyclerViewAdpter to show Items

Comment: no, annotations are not required in case of firebase. Those were for in case we are using GSON to parse json. and above is just a way to store the data in firebase and it can be anything your image or just string.

Comment: to store image in firebase you have two options either you convert them to base64 and store them in firebase or upload them on firebase storage and use uploaded link to load image in adapter using some third party library like picasso.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect your requirement correctly.

Comment: i am begginer in stackoverflow >> i dont know how to write  code inquestion